# Official structure of FHIR Anesthesia Record?

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I'm trying to port our Anesthesia record software to using FHIR. But I'm struggling to find any sort of "official" way to structure the record.

The final product should contain everything you'd see on a typical sedation record (which are *relatively* standardized.

For a sample, see this: https://az184419.vo.msecnd.net/rcdso/pdf/RCDSO_4522_PC%20Sedation%20Sample%20Record_V8_Fillable_RD.pdf

I'm trying to avoid just making up my own way to do this within FHIR if there are already established patterns for it.

Currently my plan is to use a document, by creating a FHIR Composition and using the "section" field each with corresponding "entry" fields containing referenced resources like the vital signs Observations, etc.

But currently, I'm just making up "section" titles, etc.

My question is: Is there already a formalized structure for anesthesia records or even a standard set of `section` titles a sedation record should include? I would love to see some sort of "official" sample of what one might look like.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything already existing.  However, your best bet is to search and then raise a question on http://chat.fhir.org.  You could also reach out to the HL7 Anesthesia work group (http://www.hl7.org/Special/committees/gas)

Comment: You're right.  Not much out there.  https://www.hl7.org/fhir/procedure-definitions.html  "the anesthesia MedicationAdministration is part of the surgical Procedure"  Join one of the groups and be a part of the answer!!